# Outer measure and Caratheodory measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be any set. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of singleton points $\{x\}$ , $x\in X$. Let $m$ be the set function defined on $\mathcal{C}$ with $m(\{x\})=1.$  I wish to be able to find the following and I need help/guidance:

(a) find the outer measure $m^*$ induced by $m$.
(b) find the sigma algebra of measurable sets.
(c) find the measurable functions if  $\bar{m}$ is the Caratheodory measure induced  by $m$.
(d) determine whether $(X,A,\bar{m})$ is a complete measure space, where $A$ is the sigma algebra of measurable sets.

Thanks.

For (a) I get that $m^*(\emptyset)=0$. If $E\subset \mathcal{C}$, $E$ finite, then $m^*(E) =$ number of elements in $E$. If $E$ is infinite, then $m^*(E) = \infty$. Is this right?

Comment: It is customary to show your attempts, rather than asking us to do it for you.  Start with (a).  Do you know the definition of $m^*$?  If so, what do you get in this case?

Comment: @GEdgar: I've added to my post. Is what Ive done right?

Comment: Congratulations, you did (a) yourself.

Answer (score 2):

For (b), recall that $A\subseteq X$ is measurable if $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c)$ for all $E\subseteq X$. Now, we proceed by cases: if $E$ is finite then $\mu^*(E)=|E|=|E\cap A|+|E\cap A^c|=\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c)$. On the other hand, if $E$ is infinite then either $E\cap A$ or $E\cap A^c$ are infinite, in either case both sides of the equation are infinite so the equality holds. Hence the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets is equal to the power set of $X$. The rest follows easily from this.

Comment: Is what I did for (a) right?

Comment: Also, will this be right for (c); $\bar{m}:2^X\to [0,\infty]$. for (d), can I say $(X,A,\bar{m})$ is complete since it measure space is induced by an outer measure?

Comment: You can say that, yes.  But in this case (since you know the measure and its sigma-algebra explicitly) why not check the definition of "complete"?

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks for your comment. Yes I can show completeness. However, I'm a little unsure about what the measurable functions are.

Comment: The sigma-algebra of measurable sets is the power set.  So what do you think the measurable functions are?  What is the definition of "measurable function"?

Comment: @GEdgar: Since the power set is the sigma algebra of measurable sets, any function $f:X\to \bar{R}$ is measurable since $\{x:f(x)<a\}$ for any real number $a$, is in the power set.